# Issue related to Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Acctually I am using that code for getting the facebook post data.

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;

$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx....xxxxxxx', 'scope'  => 'manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photos'));
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$rssfeed_id,'get');
```

Above code gave some error Like:-

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app thrown in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\sportsflow\sportsflow_v30\lib\base_facebook.php on line 1271
```

Please give me any solution for above define problem.

Comment: First  of all, I hope the x's where your app Id secret are supposed to be are actual numbers in your code.

Comment: Yes, I know that the x's which i used is actually app id and secret key. Thanks for your suggestion:) If u have any other idea please tell

Comment: Good! Had to make sure! :) if I am reading your error correctly it looks like Facebook wants you to create a session to store that data in.

Comment: Yes, I also think but i am not aware how to do this ?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a user to connect in order to give him the permissions.

The `Facebook()` constructor only takes an app ID and a key:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                     'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
                     'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx....xxxxxxx'));
```

The permissions should be added to the LoginUrl:

```
$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'  => 'manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photos'));
```

Once the user clicked on the login URL, you can then use the $facebook instance to get the user session:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If the user indeed exists, you can finally make the API request you want:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$rssfeed_id, 'get');
```

Follow this complete example: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! but when i using your define code, it will shows same Fatal error.Due u have any other solution??

Comment: Are you trying to run the complete example from Github? Can you launch a simple request like `$facebook->api('/me','GET');`? What is `$rssfeed_id` in your code? Can you make sure this is a valid id? I need more info. Edit your initial post if needed.

Comment: No i am not running the complete example. I am using only your code and in my code we use "$rssfeed_id" as post id.

Comment: I have an example of post id "19292868552_10150189643478553". Can u please check this particular post id in your code....

Comment: My code is not complete, it only explains the logic. You _need_ to start from the example because it provides the vital login and logout. Just don't forget to add the scopes to the login URL and to change your API request. Btw your POST ID is OK.

Comment: So, can i use the whole example from Github?

Comment: Yes, use the PHP and adapt the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your great advice...................This is right solution for my problem.:)

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue. You actually don't need user access token, just make sure in your Facebook app settings (under advanced tab) disable the "Native or Desktop app?" setting.

Comment: If you application isn't "Native or Desktop", then it's definitely legit.

Comment: This was the solution, specially useful for phonegap/cordova applications.