# Android facebook api How to read feed from public page without login?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to read feed from public page, but I get this error:

```
Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 15, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app}, isFromCache:false}
```

My steps:

1) get access token via `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]`

2) create instance of AccessToken class: `AccessToken token = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken([TOKEN_FROM_STEP1], new Date(2015,3,2), new Date(), null, permissions);`

3) open new session `session = Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(this, token, callback);`

4) and make request:

```
new Request(session, "/[PUBLIC_PAGE_ID]/feed", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            //check response
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

Where is mistake? What is the right way?

The "Native or Desktop app" setting is disabled for this app.

Comment: `Requires session when calling from a desktop app` ? Android ?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996211/issue-related-to-facebook-graph-api. Last answer fixed it for me.